# How to loop through a constantly updating list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

```
for i in range(0, len(list_stops)):
    for j in range(1, len(list_stops[i])):
        current = stops_from_stop(list_stops[i][j])
        list_stops.extend(current)
        for k in range(0, len(current)):
            for m in range(0, len(current[k])):
                list_stops_x.extend([current[k][m]])
            if id_b in list_stops_x:
                #rest of code
```

`list_stops` is a list of lists. Eg `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`

`list_stops_x` is a single list of all the numbers in list_stops. Eg `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Basically used as a condition to enter the rest of the code with a return statement at the end, so the loop does not repeat.

I find that the loop ends after reaching the final index of the first version of `list_stops`, but I am constantly extending `list_stops` and want the loop to carry on into the extensions. So for example if I extend `[7,8,9]` to `list_stops` in the loop, if `id_b` is not found I still want it to loop through `[7,8,9]`, but it stops at 6.

Note: This is only a section of the entire function, but I am quite sure the problem lies here. This is also for an introductory programming course, so a simple solution will do :) The full code is below

```
def find_path(stops, routes, stop_a, stop_b):
    id_a = stop_a[0]
    id_b = stop_b[0]
    unused = unused_stops()
    if id_b in list(unused):
        return []
    total_route = list()
    all_stops = stops_from_stop(id_a)
    list_stops_x = stops_from_stop_x(id_a)
    list_stops = stops_from_stop(id_a)
    for index in range(0, len(all_stops)):
        if id_b in all_stops[index]:
            return find_route(stops, routes, stop_a, stop_b)
    for i in range(0, len(list_stops)):
        for j in range(1, len(list_stops[i])):
            current = stops_from_stop(list_stops[i][j])
            list_stops.extend(current)
            for k in range(0, len(current)):
                for m in range(0, len(current[k])):
                    list_stops_x.extend([current[k][m]])
                    if id_b in list_stops_x:                 
                        stops_used_rev = [id_b]
                        last_route = list_stops[len(list_stops) - 1]
                        current_stop = last_route[0]
                        stops_used_rev += [current_stop]
                        for i in range(0, len(list_stops)):
                            if (current_stop in list_stops[i]) and (list_stops[i][0] == id_a):
                                stops_used_rev += [id_a]
                                break
                            elif current_stop in list_stops[i]:
                                current_stop = last_route[0]
                                stops_used_rev += [current_stop]
                        stops_used = stops_used_rev[::-1]               
                        for index in range(0, len(stops_used) - 1):                     
                            total_route.extend(find_route(stops, routes, stops[stops_used[index]], stops[stops_used[index + 1]]))
                        return total_route
```

`stops_from_stop` finds the list stops accessible from the current stop and appends to another list. `stops_from_stops_x` does the same but extends instead

Comment: did the solution i posted work for you ? if so please mark it as solved

Comment: use while loop.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that we use the range(0, len(list_stops)) if we instead use enumerate in the following way, **BEWARE INFINITE LOOP**, due too we keep adding elements to the list. So be careful, but this should give the desired result. I have changed some part of the code so I could run it.

Enumerate makes it possible to both get the item of the list (val) and the index that we are currently at.

```py
list_stops = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
list_stops_x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
newer = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
id_b = 9

for i, val in enumerate(list_stops):
    print(val)
    for j in range(1, len(list_stops[i])):

        current = newer
        list_stops.extend(current)

        for k in range(0, len(current)):
            for m in range(0, len(current[k])):
                list_stops_x.extend([current[k][m]])

            # if id_b in list_stops_x:
            #     print("id_b in")
            #     break
```

**EDIT 1**

in your code that was in the edit suggestion you have loops that look like the following:

```py
for i in range(0, len(list_stops)):
   ...
```

These should be replace with the following to fix the issue

```py
for i, val in enumerate(list_stops):
   ...
```

I have a difficult time of testing the code, but try replace the for loops with the type that i provided and let me know

**Edit 2**

If we keep adding to the list ofcourse it will loop infinitely unless we exit somewhere. You can see this example that I add elements to list *a* from list *b* and then remove the item. As you see from the output we loop eight times so we know it works, you should reflect such changes in your code

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]


for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    print("Loop Count: " + str(idx))
    if b:
        a.append(b[0])
        b.remove(b[0])
```

```
Loop Count: 0
Loop Count: 1
Loop Count: 2
Loop Count: 3
Loop Count: 4
Loop Count: 5
Loop Count: 6
Loop Count: 7
```

Comment: Hi Shadesfear, sorry for the late reply, I only just had the chance to try it! It did not work as we hoped. It took a while to return an answer and the answer seems to have repeated itself many times. Could it be that the rest of my code had to be adapted to yours?

Comment: Well some of it might have to, can you just update your post to show me what you have now ?

Comment: hi shadesfear, i just posted the full function :)

Comment: stops and routes are just csv files which i imported

Comment: The edits you made were rejected, you should add them to the original post. 
I will just update my answer to reflect what i think that needs to be done

Comment: Oh I just updated to my original post. Sorry I'm still quite new to Stack

Comment: I tried with your suggested edit. It causes an infinite loop, but that could be due to my bottom part of the code